# python can't logging messages to cmd

Tags: python, logging

My code as below, the problem is log.info("message") can't be printed to my console and log.error("message") can:

```
log = None

def initLogger():
    global log
    log = logging.getLogger("JsSDKBuilder")
    console = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
    console.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('[%(levelname)s] %(message)s'))
    log.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    log.addHandler(console)


def main():
    """Preprocessing"""
    initLogger()
    log.info("info message") //!!!!!!!!!!CANT PRINT OUT PLEASE HELP!!!!!!!
    log.error("error message") //works as expected


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

sorry wired,i run the code in my virtual machine again,it works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of your own code, use this:

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to `global log` at the top of your `main()` ?